# How to skip the teardown section in Gallio/MbUnit from a test case

Tags: c#, automated-tests, watin, mbunit, gallio

I'm using Gallio/MbUnit with WatiN and I have a defined method to executes as TearDown, what I need is a way to skip the TearDown from a specific Test Case, is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to skip the TearDown method for a particular test method. I ran into a similar need with MBUnit, so what I did instead, was removed the SetUp and TearDown methods. I then created a factory class that would do the needed SetUp/Teardown for me utilizing a "using" statement. Example:

```
    [Test]
    public void Folder_GetPropertyType_Valid()
    {
        using (var folder = IntegrationUtil.GetFolder())
        {
            PropId pid = folder.Properties.ElementAt(FolderMockConstants.FOLDER_FIRST_ELEMENT);
            Assert.AreEqual(FolderMockConstants.FOLDER_VALID_PROPERTY_TYPE, folder.GetPropertyType(pid));
        }
    }
```

In this case, I use the factory IntegrationUtil to get an object instance of a folder, and things get cleaned up after the "using" brackets. This test was pulled out of an MBUnit test class which did not have any Setup/TearDown methods included.

Hope this helps.